# How to use Wimax modem?

Tags: installation, drivers, usb-modem, 4g

I have a Wimax 4G modem, but no activity in Ubuntu 12.10.

How can I get a driver for this?

Here's full info on the device:

> Banglalion WiMAX
>   5Vdc, 300ma
>   Model Name: WIXUBB-116X238BD
>   FCC ID: MXF-WIXUBB-116
>   MAC: 20107A9CEF64
>   S/N: BCL120821001932
>   Made in China

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a lot of trouble trying to get this thing to work properly. I'd recommend swapping out that modem for a WiMAX wifi hotspot instead.